# How to handle margin-left correctly?

Tags: css, css-position, margin, margin-left

The position of the `portfolio` page is well positioned but I think I don't use correctly propriety `margin-left`, I think that I have to use another propriety?

[image]

Then, my second problem is that my `languages` page is too far from  my `portfolio` page, I would like to fix to `50 px`. But I cannot do because I am stuck with my first problem.

[image]

Thank you for help.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header{
 background-color: #B1DBE8;
 height: 98px;
}

.header-block{
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 8px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #777;
 line-height: 20px;
}

.page-left{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 430px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-block">
    <div class="page-left">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="page-left">Languages</div>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: I don't think teh `.page-left` class works as you showed in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `selector` for your code for the second question:

> View the result in full screen for actual `margin-left` working.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header{
 background-color: #B1DBE8;
 height: 98px;
}

.header-block{
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 8px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #777;
 line-height: 20px; 
}

.page-left{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 430px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.Languages{
 display: inline-block;
margin-left: 30px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-block">
    <div class="page-left">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="Languages">Languages</div>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you @joel, vote the answer if you think if it is worth voting.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin-left: 430px;` to the header-block div

Answer (score -1):

You can use "flex" it's help you
In different screen sizes It will help arrange the right proportions

Try.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header{
 background-color: #B1DBE8;
 height: 98px;
}

.header-block{
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 8px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #777;
 line-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.page-first{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 430px;
}
.page-second{
 margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-block">
    <div class="page-first">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="page-second">Languages</div>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Example.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: First : no need to create `flex` when you create new selector class, second : what is this `display: inline-second;` ?

Comment: Actually, display: inline-second; Not needed

Comment: No I mean what is it 'inline-second`? I never heard of that property? and I am not the one who downvoted! FYI